# Cannot access memory at address (C)

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, integer, substring

I have a C project that is getting an error on these functions:

```
char * devolveIDDistritoDoConcelho(char *id_concelho)
{
    return getSubstring(id_concelho, 0,2);
}

int devolveIndexDistritoDoConcelho(char *id_concelho)
{
    int i = stringToInt(devolveIDDistritoDoConcelho(id_concelho))-1;
    return i;
}
```

```
char * getSubstring(char *string, int startIndex, int length)
{
    char *substring=(char *)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(substring, &string[startIndex], length);
    substring[length] = '\0';
    return substring;
}
int stringToInt(char * str)
{
    return (int)strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10);
}
```

Everything goes well and as I see in the debugger, (at least before returning) the value in *substring* is  "01" for a source string "0101", but when it enters function stringToInt, the debugger gives value `"0xffffffffffffffd0 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffd0>"` for parameter *str*, and program exits.

I have tried a lot of stuff but the problem doesn't go away, can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thank you

Comment: Show the code that calls `devolveIndexDistritoDoConcelho`. Show a [mcve]

Comment: @Tiago And why are you trying to access the memory at this address? Is it so difficult to determine why this address appeared?!

Comment: You have a memory leak. One malloc without free. You use the getSubstring return as parameter to stringToInt losing the pointer to free this memory.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's kind of complex, but weirdly enough when I try to create a MRE sending the value that is being sent in the project to `devolveIndexDistritoDoConcelho` it works, but on the project it doesn't

Comment: Jabberwocky I am debugging in VSCode with GCC which is turning out to be a nightmare

Comment: @SuperG280 thank you very much! this was exactly it, I am now sending a pointer instead of returning

Comment: @SuperG280 can you reply as an answer so I cant accept it?